# SQL lex yacc grammar

Tags: sql, yacc, lex

All,

**Developing a validating application for embedded sql**

i'll use ansi c or c++ as developement language

Where do i get an sql grammar for lex and yacc?

Comment: A quick search for "SQL BNF" brought up this first http://savage.net.au/SQL/

Comment: thnks Joe i really need lex yacc solution

Comment: MySQl and PostgreSQL both use yacc for their grammar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

hi there is a solution in google projects yaxx:

yac [file](https://github.com/wclever/NdYaccLexTool/blob/master/progs/sql2.y):
lex [file](https://github.com/wclever/NdYaccLexTool/blob/master/progs/scn2.l)

enjoy

Comment: The same problem, I want to implement as the author, but in my case there are such commands in SQL like nextval, setval, etc, is there any extension for yak and lex files for my case? (from postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

There is book named "flex & bison" by John Levine (Author). in this book there is a complete chapter for sql parser. you can download this book for free [here](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~sumeet/flex__bison.pdf)