# Implicit Cursor on SQL Grammar

Tags: sql, database, cursor

I was using the grammar from post: [SQL lex yacc grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656926/sql-lex-yacc-grammar)

When i analyze the gammar I saw that every "select statement" has to preceed by a cursor.

I saw that oracle database puts a implicit cursor (in case that you dont declare it explicit).

EDIT:

Look ate this doc:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm

> **select_statement**
>
> SQL SELECT statement (not PL/SQL SELECT INTO statement). For
>   select_statement, PL/SQL declares, opens, fetches from, and closes an
>   implicit cursor. However, because select_statement is not an
>   independent statement, the implicit cursor is internal—you cannot
>   reference it with the name SQL.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/sql_cursor.htm

> **SQL (Implicit) Cursor Attribute**
>
> A SQL (implicit) cursor is opened by the database to process each SQL
>   statement that is not associated with an explicit cursor. Every SQL
>   (implicit) cursor has six attributes, each of which returns useful
>   information about the execution of a data manipulation statement.

Is it normal in other databases?

Thanks

Comment: Please be careful of tagging.  Flex is for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework and Flex-lexer is for the lexical analyzer.

Comment: It is a common mistake and I can understand why.  If I Could figure out how to make that distinction show up in the 'roll over text' for Flex; I would.

Comment: @Reboog711: Edit the tag excerpt. The comment is in the tag info but it's way too far down for people to see.

Comment: Why do you think that the select statement must be preceded by a cursor? You can derive `sql_list -> sql ';' -> manipulative_statement ';' -> select_statement ';'` without any cursor intervening.

Comment: I think, you forgot to look at the definition of select_statement.

select_statement:
  SELECT opt_all_distinct selection
  INTO target_commalist
  table_exp
 ;

Comment: @Rubber: where in that definition of select statement do you see a cursor? It starts with the word "SELECT", continues with ALL or DISTINCT (optionally) and then a selection... but no cursor that I can see.

Comment: Following the rules: cursor_def -> query_exp -> query_term -> query_spec -> SELECT opt_all_distinct selection table_exp. Using this rule i can write a query like "DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE_01"

In the select_statement, we have the INTO and it is obligatory. We could not write a query like "select * from table_01" using the select_statement rule.

Comment: @Rubber. Ah, good point. But you can't write your select statement using the cursor declaration either, without leaving out the `DECLARE` part. Since the grammar you're using is intended as a demonstration of a parser technology and is not, afaik, used as an actual grammar file in any SQL implementation, I don't think you can draw many conclusions from it. I did find this site which claims to have extracted BNF directly from the SQL 2003 spec: http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#direct%20SQL%20statement

Answer (score 0):

This is an Oracle semantic rule, not a grammar issue, and certainly not a lexical issue.